# A Kalman Filter for RSSI Distance approximations

Tags: c#, rssi, kalman-filter

I'm currently working on a project that makes use of RSSI signals to determine a users distance from between three beacons. Whilst I have the rough triangulation formulas working, I'm trying to make something a lot more accurate.

Through all my research, I have discovered Kalman filters. From what I've been reading about them, they seem to be just what I'm wanting to use. However, all of the examples I have found have been fairly complex and difficult to understand.

Has anyone ever used a Kalmon filter combined with an RSSI signal before? 
Is anyone capable of point me, or explaining to me, how a Kalmon filters work in a simple way?

Comment: You can check http://www.bzarg.com/p/how-a-kalman-filter-works-in-pictures/ for a good explanation

Comment: Another interesting paper https://www.wouterbulten.nl/projects/slacjs/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Has anyone ever used a Kalmon filter combined with an RSSI signal before?

Yes, see for example: [RSSI-Based Indoor Localization and Tracking Using Sigma-Point Kalman Smoothers](http://www.cse.ogi.edu/~anindya/Paul_Wan_Plans08.pdf)

> Is anyone capable of point me, or explaining to me, how a Kalmon filters work in a simple way?

The most human readable intro with examples I have found so far is the [SIGGRAPH Course Pack](http://www.cs.unc.edu/~tracker/media/pdf/SIGGRAPH2001_CoursePack_08.pdf).